# What is Quickset64 on my Dell machine?

Tags: windows-7, dell-studio

I was browsing through my list of installed programs to come across some Dell shipped with my computer. One of them is called "Quickset64".

I did some Googling and learnt that it's supposed to take care of my wireless network card, however, I also noticed that at boot-up the program opens a window saying my battery is at the end of its lifespan.

What is this program actually supposed to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dell Quickset performs a variety of functions based on the computer/laptop it shipped with.

Some functions:

- Allows extra buttons on the computer to properly function.  Buttons like enable/disable wireless functions, sleep, screen brightness, etc.
- Battery functions like charge and health
- possibly more

Do you need it?  Not necessarily, however some of your computer's extra features might not work without it.  There is no harm in running it.